# Can ps command show genuine argv[] arguments passed to a process?

Tags: ps

This is a subtle problem I find today. The `ps` command can show command arguments for a process, but I find the feature crippled.

For a shell command line like this:

```
gdbserver localhost:5050 testg "hello world" 123
```

We know that `gdbserver`'s `main()` will see:

| argv[] | C string |
| --- | --- |
| argv[1] | localhost:5050 |
| argv[2] | testg |
| argv[3] | hello world |
| argv[4] | 123 |

However, `ps -ef` shows

```
gdbserver localhost:5050 testg hello world 123
```

So it looks like `argv[3]` is `hello`, which is so misleading.

So may question is clear, is there way to have ps show genuine `argv[]` values? `man ps` does not seem to refer to this issue. If it can't, any alternative tools?

Here is a screen shot from Ubuntu Linux 20.04.
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead.

Comment: But I really want to doodle(draw lines and arrows, with colors) on the screenshot, to highlight/emphasize the problem. This is much more eye-catching(=less brain burning) than just paste plain text.

Comment: Maybe for you, but not for the majority of the people who have to read your brain burning pics. Your doodles don't add anything necessary either. See https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/158442

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, PS can not (I think), but you can get it from proc e.g. `/proc/PID/cmdline` the cmdline file is a null separated list of the args of a program so this script will parce it

```
hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X "' /proc/PID/cmdline  | sed 's/00/0a/g' | xxd -r -p
```

- `hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X "' /proc/PID/cmdline` will dump the file as hex each bite has a space in between it.
- `sed 's/00/0a/g'` replaces the 00 (null) with 0a (line ending or new line)
- `xxd -r -p` takes the hex and converts it back to binary
  So the output will be a list of args with a new line in between them.

Comment: Another option: `printf %q` to quote the value: `cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline | xargs -0 printf "%q "; echo`

Comment: Why use `hexdump` at all, if the same `xxd` can be used for forward conversion? Example: `xxd -p /proc/PID/cmdline | sed 's/00/0a/g' | xxd -r -p`

Comment: I did not know about that, and this won't work if this get out putted be `xxd -p` `2002` is gets replaced with `20a2` when no substation should have happened.